# Data tables exercise

Tags: sql, database

Hi everyone I was working through a databases exercise and came across the following exercise where I have to create a set of data tables from a given case scenario. But I'm having difficulty working out the attributes in bold:

*A database is to be designed for a university to monitor students’ progress 
throughout their course of study. The students are studying for a degree (such as 
BSc, MSc, etc.) within the framework of a modular system. The university provides 
a number of modules, each  being characterised by its code, title, credit value, 
module leader, academic staff and the department they come from. A module is coordinated by a module leader who shares teaching duties with one or more 
lecturers. A lecturer may teach (and be a module leader for) more than one module. 
Students are free to choose any module they wish but the following rules must be 
observed:  some modules require pre-requisite modules and some degree 
programmes have compulsory modules. The database is also to contain some 
information about students including their  student  numbers, names, addresses, 
degrees they  study for, and their past performance (i.e., modules taken and 
examination results).*

So far the tables I have are:

**University**

*ModuleCode, ModuleTitle, CreditValue, Department*

**Module**

*ModuleCode, ModuleTitle, LecturerID*

**Lecturer**

*LecturerID, ModuleCode, ModuleTitle*

**Student**

*StudentID, Name, Address, DegreeCode*

**Degree**

*DegreeCode, DegreeType, DegreeTitle*

**Performance**

*ModuleCode, ModuleTitle, StudentID, Result*

Is there anything that I'm missing out on or can improve?

Comment: @Downvoter - please clarify to the OP as to why you downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts (in no particular order):

- I would have assumed there is a one-to-one relationship between `ModuleId` and `ModuleTitle`.  That is, that a `ModuleId` uniquely identifies a `ModuleTitle`.  In that case, you shouldn't be be using both `ModuleId` and `ModuleTitle` everywhere you're identifying a module, but use only the uniquely identifying value.  (Except in the table where the relationship between `ModuleId` and `ModuleTitle` is defined.)
- Lecturers can teach multiple modules.  Yet, you've include the `ModuleId` as part of the Lecturers table.  See the problem here?
- Is the `LecturerId` in the module table intended to be the moduleLeader?  If so, say that.  A foreign key doesn't always have to be the same name as the primary -- in general it's a good idea, but you want to clarify that this is a special lecturer.  Or perhaps, you want to add a table that specifically identifies which lecturers are module leaders.
- I don't see anything here that implements the 'some modules require pre-requisite modules and some degree programmes have compulsory modules' requirements.
- In would interpret 'the department they come from' as referring to the academic staff, not to the module itself.  It's not clear that a module could only be taught by people from one academic department.
- In the real world addresses are much more complicated then just saying `address` as a field.

The last point is somewhat nit-picky, but the rest should be addressed.  I think you've still got some significant work to iron out these issues.

In general, I think you're going to need to break this out into more tables, to represent each of the individual entities (modules, lecturers, departments, and then build tables to define the relationships between them.

Answer (score 1):

On the first pass, I'd read the description like this. (Possible tables in bold, some bolded more than once.)

> A database is to be designed for a university to monitor **students**’
>   **progress** throughout their **course of study**. The **students** are studying
>   for a **degree** (such as BSc, MSc, etc.) within the framework of a
>   modular system. The university provides a number of **modules**, each
>   being characterised by its code, title, credit value, **module leader**,
>   **academic staff** and the **department** they come from. A module is
>   coordinated by a module leader who shares **teaching duties** with one or
>   more **lecturers**. A lecturer may teach (and be a module leader for) more
>   than one module. Students are free to choose any module they wish but
>   the following rules must be observed: some modules require
>   **pre-requisite modules** and some **degree programmes have compulsory
>   modules**. The database is also to contain some information about
>   **students** including their student numbers, names, addresses, degrees
>   they study for, and their past performance (i.e., modules taken and
>   **examination results**).

Since this is for one university, I probably wouldn't create a table of universities, although I could make a good case either way.